# Export report not showing fields

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export, order-grid

I want to export order report in csv.

With following content

```
Order Date
Order Day
Order Id
Ip Address
Customer Name
Customer Group
Billing Name
Billing Address
Billing City
Billing Postcode
Billing State
Billing Country
Billing Country Code
Billing Email Address
Billing Phone No
Billing Mobile No
Shipping Name
Shipping Address
Shipping City
Shipping Postal Code
Shipping State
Shipping Country
Shipping Country Code
Shipping Email Address
Shipping Telephone No
Shipping Mobile No
Tracking Company Name
Tracking No
Tracking Url
Marketplace Type
Payment Type
Payment Transaction Id
Marketplace ID
Product Title
Category Name
Brand Name
Weight
Quantity
Product Price
Gross Total
Discount Amount
Gross Amount After Discount
Shipping Cost
Tax Amount
Tax Name
Net Amount
Order Status
Last Activities
```

I tried this code for Ip address in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` and `function _prepareCollection()`

```
$this->addColumn('remote_ip', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ip address'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'remote_ip',
    ));
```

But it is not showing anything in `Ip address` field.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have this in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` class and in `_prepareColumns` function.

```
$this->addColumn('remote_ip', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ip address'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'remote_ip',
    ));
```

This will add new column called `Ip address` in sales grid.

**If your order is created from admin then this field will be empty.**

I would suggest not to edit core code directly, instead you should override it.

Comment: I think that's the same code I used @AdarshKhatri

Comment: If your order is created from admin then this field will be empty.

Comment: I am seeing all fields are empty @AdarshKhatri but there is entry of ip in database `sales_flat_order` table

Comment: Are you adding the code in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid.php` file? if you are then can you show me your `Grid.php`?

Comment: Great, please mark as solved to help others.

Comment: Can tell answer for this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117086/how-to-get-tax-name @AdarshKhatri