# How to get tax name

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, tax

I can get tax amount by

```
$order->getTaxAmount();
```

But how can I get tax name applied to order.

I used this

```
$taxClassId = $order->getTaxClassId();
$taxClassName = Mage::getModel('tax/class')->load($taxClassId)->getClassName();
```

But it is not working.

Any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order data doesn't hold `tax class id` ([check what can you get from order regarding tax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471813/magento-order-tax-information)), which is why you cannot get it from there. But you can work around to it.

You can call tax class this way:

```
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item){
   $productId = $item->getProductId();
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
   $taxClassId = $_product->getTaxClassId();
   $taxClass = Mage::getModel('tax/class')->load($taxClassId);
   $taxClassName = $taxClass->getClassName();
   echo $taxClassName."<br>";
}
```

Since tax class is applied to individual product in magento, it may have different class for different products within a order.

Here we are going through each item in order and then getting tax class of those items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you answer this @AdarshKhatri http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119706/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getparentitem

Comment: But tax class id for a product can be changed and if you want to get info from an old order/item you get the wrong value ... I am not sure how it works but tax class are recorded here for every order_item `sales_order_tax_item`

Comment: $order->getFullTaxInfo() this might have the code right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Community edition 1.6+, the catalog module has a very nice method to get tax name without loading the entire product.

Here is how to achieve it:

```
$_resource = $this->getProduct()->getResource();
$items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item){
   $productId = $item->getProductId();
   $taxClassId = $_resource->getAttributeRawValue($_item, 'tax_class_id', Mage::app()->getStore());
   $taxClass = Mage::getModel('tax/class')->load($taxClassId);
   $taxClassName = $taxClass->getClassName();
   echo $taxClassName;
   echo PHP_EOL;
}
```