# Fatal error: Call to a member function getParentItem()

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, print

When I try to print shipment I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getParentItem() on null in
>   /public_html/includes/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Shipment.php on
>   line 121

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you try recompiling under System > Tools > Compilation ?

Comment: Yes tried but its not working @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: What are you trying to print? Does it work for other pdf types? Do you have any custom product types or extensions that change product behaviour?

Comment: I am trying to print shipment , all others prints are working @KristofatFooman

Comment: This error indicates your code is trying to execute some method in a item which is not well registered in your database. A corrupt database is a really big problem, specially if it involves database sales related tables. This happens with a concrete shipment, or it is a general problem?

Comment: @RaulSanchez didn't get. How to solve this error?

Comment: Have you changed any code? Or did you delete any shipment from database?